# Find good substitution for PDE.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, proof-verification

Consider system of : $\begin{cases}
   u_{tt} = \vartriangle{u} 
   \\
   u|_{t = 0} = \frac{1}{x^{2}+y^2+z^2}
   \\
   u_t|_{t = 0} = 0
 \end{cases}$

I've thought about $v = x^{2} + y^2+z^2$, then $v_{x} = 2x, v_{y} = 2y, v_{z} = 2z$. Hence we have : $\vartriangle{u} = 6u_{v} + 4v u_{v} = u_{tt}$. And addititional property is : $u|_{t=0} = \frac{1}{v}$.

But how should I finish it?

*Edit* :

After spherical substitution and deducing that $U(x,y,z,t) = U(r,t)$

We have :  $\begin{cases}
   u_{tt} = u_{rr} + \frac{2}{r}u_{r} 
   \\
   u|_{t = 0} = \frac{1}{r^2}
   \\
   u_t|_{t = 0} = 0
 \end{cases}$

After substitution: $\xi = t-r$ and $\eta = t + r$ we have 
$u_{\xi \eta} = \frac{u_{\eta} - u_{\xi}}{\eta - \xi}$. The solution for this part is :
$U(\xi,\eta) = \frac{f(\eta)+ g(\xi)}{\eta - \xi}$. Hence we have :

$U(t,r) = \frac{f(t+r) +g(t-r)}{2r}$ with initial data : $U(0,r) = \frac{1}{r^2}$ and $U_t(0,r) = 0$.

But now how can we find exact form of $f$ and $g$?

Comment: Have a look at the Laplacian in spherical coordinates [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_operator#Three_dimensions). The solution is radial: depends only on $r$, not on $\theta,\phi$.

Comment: @Federico I've thought about spherical coordinates. But Laplacian looks terrible. Why should solution depends only of $r$? Suppose function $f = t r \theta \phi + \frac{t}{r^{2}}$ depends on all variables , but $f_t = \frac{1}{r^2}$

Comment: initial datum is radially simmetric. you need also to specify the initial value of $\partial_t u$. i assume it is $0$

Comment: @Federico there is only one initial property. So the task assumes to find all solutions.

Comment: good luck then...

Comment: @Federico but if we suppose that $u_t |_{t = 0} = 0$ when what ? I mean what is the way to finish with finding the exact form?

Comment: $f = \dfrac{1}{t+r}$ and $g = -\dfrac{1}{t-r}$ satisfy the conditions